# Immediate signing in after logout causes redirection to home page

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a common login and logout screen. When i logout after signing in... I come to signin page. Default behavior of spring security invalidates the session on logout so if i try to sign-in using the same screen, i get redirected to home page as there is no session available at that point. The desired behavior should be able to sign-in immediately after sign-out, which is not happening due to session invalidation

```
<http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/access-denied">
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/user/sign-up" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/user/sign-in" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/**" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/dashboard/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_IC')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"
        requires-channel="http" />
    <form-login login-page="/secured/user/sign-in" 
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/secured/user/sign-in" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/secured/user/sign-in?loggedout=true"
        logout-url="/secured/logout"/>
    <security:session-management
        session-fixation-protection="none">
    </security:session-management>
</http>
```

If you refer to the xml, you will see `/secured/user/sign-in` is used for both sign-in and sign-out

How can I handle this issue ?

Comment: I don't understand the question completely ... after you log out you get redirected to log in again ? Could you please describe the desired behavior.

Comment: I have a common login and logout screen. When i logout after signing in... I come to signin page. Default behavior of spring security invalidates the session on logout so if i try to sign-in using the same screen, i get redirected to home page as there is no session available at that point. The desired behavior should be able to sign-in immediately after sign-out, which is not happening due to session invalidation. Let me know if u need more clarifications

Comment: @abhi No, this is perfect, thanks.

Comment: @abhi Not that I can think of so far. I haven't given it much time though. I'll probably have time to look at it a bit more today. Could you post your security namespace config please ?

Comment: @abhi also if you have debug log enabled the output from that would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a work around for this issue by using `invalidate-session="false"`

Answer (score 0):

I think that as a "for now" solution.

You can:

1. Declare your own `HttpSessionEventPublisher` in your web.xml:

   ```
   <listener>
       <listener-class>org.yourcompany.MyHttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```
2. In the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` grab the `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` and don't allow spring to invalidate the seesion.

I'm not sure if this s a 'correct' solution, but it should work.

Comment: this is already available in spring as invalidate-session="false" but need to know how not to use it because i want to invalidate session after logout